# Angular UI grid column filter doesnt appear after pin / unpin column:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using latest version of angular UI grid.

Angular UI grid filter doesnt appear after pin / unpin column:

Steps to follow:

1. Pin any column (Email / phone) etc.
2. Unpin same column
3. Now click toggle filtering button
4. Textbox for filtering on same column doesnt appear

I have created plunker to demonstrate this:

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/aSEvO4EWDTyK4yg6PiQd?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/aSEvO4EWDTyK4yg6PiQd?p=preview)
```

I tried refreshing grid / notifyDataChange, but seems doesnt work. Please suggest possible solutions.

Comment: THis is correct link 
http://plnkr.co/edit/aSEvO4EWDTyK4yg6PiQd?p=preview

Comment: Swapnil :- Did you find any solutions regarding this ?? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I am still looking for solution. No solution till now